# How to stack Tensors images

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, stack

I'm trying to do Pix2Pix NN, my input is on Grayscale and my output will be on RGB, I'm using

```
stacked_image = tf.stack([inimg, tgimg], axis=0)
```

to stack the images to do data augmentation, the images were loaded using

```
inimg = tf.cast(tf.image.decode_jpeg(tf.io.read_file(INPATH + filename)), tf.float32)[..., :3]
tgimg = tf.cast(tf.image.decode_jpeg(tf.io.read_file(OUPATH + filename)), tf.float32)[..., :3]
```

But I got an error about the shapes.

```
InvalidArgumentError: Shapes of all inputs must match: values[0].shape = [286,286,1] != values[1].shape = [286,286,3] [Op:Pack] name: stack
```

Some advice about how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can only use tf.stack if the shapes of inimg and tgimg are the same. You can achieve this using tf.tile

```
stacked_image = tf.stack([tf.tile(inimg, [1, 1, 3]), tgimg], axis=0)
```

stacked_image will have shape (2, 286, 286, 3)